# application not installed error on device but works on AVD

Tags: android

I am trying to install and run the app on AVD and it successfully does but when I try to deploy my app on any android device as specified target it completes installation and when I am trying to open it says "`application not installed`". somebody help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="adhoc.voip"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi.direct" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



    <application
         android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_CHECKIN_PROPERTIES">

        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".MenuActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <service 
            android:name=".ConnectionService">
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: is your device have API 14 or greater?
does it have wifi direct?

Comment: yes im using Galaxy GT-N8000 tab which has wifi direct and also API level 18..

Answer (score 0):

Please mention targetSdKVersion in manifest file.

```
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

Comment: bro thnx fr the answer.. and i wld like to tell u tat my application is based on Wif_direct feature which is only available on API level of 14 and higher so i cannot lower my minimum API level than 14...

Answer (score 0):

You need not mention targetSdkVersion in your manifest on compulsory basis, but make sure your minimumSdkVersion is compatible with your phone.

Comment: thnx fr the answer and i have tried adding targetSdkVersion to 18..and also deleting the "ACCESS.CEHCKIN.PROPERTIES" line from <application> element...it has helped to open but now the application is saying .. "unfortunately stopped working"

Comment: post your logcat @NavalChippa

Comment: send me your email bro..ill mail my log cat.. im findin it bit difficult ova here..